# How to improve Data transfer speed using TCP sockets

Tags: image, opencv, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

This code is for the server

```
import socket, cv2, pickle,struct,imutils

# Socket Create
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name  = socket.gethostname()
host_ip ='192.168.xx.xxx' #socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
print('HOST IP:',host_ip)
port = 1234
socket_address = (host_ip,port)
source = 'video.mp4'
# Socket Bind
server_socket.bind(socket_address)

# Socket Listen
server_socket.listen(5)
print("LISTENING AT:",socket_address)

# Socket Accept
while True:
    client_socket,addr = server_socket.accept()
    print('GOT CONNECTION FROM:',addr)
    if client_socket:
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
                
        while(vid.isOpened()):
            img,frame = vid.read()
            a = pickle.dumps(frame)
            message = struct.pack("Q",len(a))+a
            client_socket.sendall(message)
            
            cv2.imshow('TRANSMITTING VIDEO',frame1)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if key ==ord('q'):
                client_socket.close()
```

This is client code

```
import socket,cv2, pickle,struct

# create socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_ip = '192.168.xx.xxx' # paste your server ip address here
port = 1234
client_socket.connect((host_ip,port)) # a tuple
data = b""
payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
while True:
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        packet = client_socket.recv(4096*4096) # 4K
        if not packet: break
        data+=packet

    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("Q",packed_msg_size)[0]
    
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += client_socket.recv(4096*4096)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data  = data[msg_size:]
    frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
    cv2.imshow("RECEIVING VIDEO",frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key  == ord('q'):
        break
client_socket.close()
```

I am pretty new to this, I got a sample code from pyshine.com and I modified that code to cater my need. If I am sending 2k video using this code, it takes up a significant amount of time, while if I send any video of less resolution, it works faster. Can anyone help, how can I get rid of this issue?

I tried changing the buffer size from 4096*4096 to a higher value, it didn't help much. I actually wanted to stream a 2k video from my system to another system.

Note : As an end goal, I want to use each of the recieved frame for some processing using Yolo. I have a `runYolo()` function and I need to do the processing. When I incoperate this, it is even slow

Comment: If your video is 1080p (i.e. 1920x1080), you are sending 6MB (1920x1080x3) per frame, so if you want 30 fps, you need 180MB/s bandwidth which is around double what gigabit Ethernet can handle. You need to compress each frame with JPEG or some such, then each one will be 300kB or so, instead of 6MB and it will go 20x faster, or so.

Comment: You are taking a compressed file (video.mp4), decompress it into single frames, convert these binary data to a string (pickle) - each of these steps is adding more and more overhead. Then you transport these "exploded" data over a socket. The problem here is not that you need to increase the speed of data transfer, but that you need to make better use of the available bandwidth by using video compression (as mp4 already provides).

Comment: You'd probably be better off just using `ffmpeg` at the command line instead of Python.